# how to get value of a plain text when click a radio button android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to get the value of a EditText when the user clicks the other radio button. I wrote the code but it didn't work correctly.

When I select the Other Specify Radio button, I can't get the value of the EditText but if I click one of the other radio buttons first and after that if I click the other specify radio button then I can get the value of the EditText

[image: Screenshot of app with three radio buttons]

Here's the code:

```java
public void PackageRGOnClick(View view) {

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.singlePlayRadiobtn:
                if(checked){
                    packageDetails="Single";
                }
                break;
            case R.id.doublePlayRadiobtn:
                if(checked){
                    packageDetails="Double";
                }
                break;
            case R.id.otherRadiobtn:
                if(checked){
                    packageDetails=otherPackageRadio.getText().toString().trim();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Layout file:

```xml
<EditText
                            android:id="@+id/OtherPackageRadiotxt"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            app:backgroundTint="@color/lightGray"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/packageBartxt" />

                        <RadioGroup
                            android:id="@+id/packageRadioGroup"
                            android:layout_width="283dp"
                            android:layout_height="101dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/packageBartxt">

                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/singlePlayRadiobtn"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:checked="true"
                                android:buttonTint="@color/midblue"
                                android:text="Single"
                                android:onClick="PackageRGOnClick"/>

                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/doublePlayRadiobtn"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:buttonTint="@color/midblue"
                                android:text="Double"
                                android:onClick="PackageRGOnClick" />

                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/otherRadiobtn"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:buttonTint="@color/midblue"
                                android:text="Other Specify"
                                android:onClick="PackageRGOnClick" />
                        </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Do you have any text in your edit text when you click on your "Other' radio button? My guess is first you are clicking on the radio button and then entering text into the edit text. In that case it wont work because when the radio button is clicked there is no text in the edit text.

Comment: What is actually `packageDetails` type and where do you set text for `EditText`? If you could provide us a bit more code with `EditText` logic it would be easier.

Comment: oh no thanks for help i forget to select the radio button after i type the value in edit text .my bad :)

Comment: By the way, you could use `RadioGroup` with `OnCheckedChangeListener` to make your life easier :)